How can I create a shape like this?

Hello.
I want to create an image in Illustrator or Photoshop where light comes out and blends like the one above.
I wonder if there is another way other than drawing it one by one.
thank you.

Don't think of it as "light". It's just colors. Mostly just gradients.

There are probably a million ways of doing it, even using 3D if you really want. I think the question is a bit too vague, maybe you can check out some illustrator gradient / mesh tutorials and/or Photoshop blur tools? What do you mean 'drawing one by one'?
